# ReactJS variables problems. It's updating variables that are not being touched

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a ReactJS app and i'm a new comer.
I have a Component like this

```
class Type extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                name : props.type.name,
                description : props.type.description,
                price : props.type.price,
                imageList :  props.type.images,
                mode : 'view',
                // i'm cloning the whole object
                clone : props.type
            };
        }

        handleDeleteImage(event) {
            const imageId = event.target.getAttribute('data-imageId');
            // get the current imageList of this Component
            var imageList = this.state.imageList;

            // checking the length of 2 image list before removing the
            // targeted image 
            console.log(imageList.length) // displays 3
            console.log(this.state.clone.images.length) // displays 3

            // remove the targeted imageId
            imageList.splice(imageId, 1);

            // checking the length of 2 image list after removing the
            // targeted image 
            console.log(imageList.length) // displays 2
            console.log(this.state.clone.images.length) // displays 2        
        }
}
```

So what i'm doing here is i want to clone the object so when the user changes there mind and doesn't want to make changes anymore, they can hit the cancel button and everything is back to the state they were before (i have a function to handle this as well. I set the fields -name, description, price- to the values of the clone)
But as you can see, i didn't touched the image list in the clone at all still it got changed anyway.
Am i doing anything wrong here?
Thank you for any help.

---

Hey guys! So I realized that the concept I used in this service is not so efficient.
Like @Michael McQuade said, I should control the data in one flow only which is changing the data in the parent Component, not the child ones. I also reviewed the [ReactJS Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html) and I can see why.
But with that being said. Let's say I'm working on a Component which has lots of Child-Component, does that mean I have to callback all the way up to the Parent Component to make changes in the Child one? And does that mean i must have multiple handlers in the Parent one that will be passed down to the Child that needs them?
I hope my question doesn't border you guys. Thanks!

Comment: You should not mutate your state with `splice`. Use `setState` to update your state instead.

Comment: hi! i'm justing trying to test everthing before setting the new State.

Comment: Use " imageList :  [...props.type.images] " in this.state, This way you will preserve the original array.

Comment: @Rishabh ahh, that worked out. I didn't know it has to be done in such way. I guest that is what Moti Korets and Stundji trying to say too. Thank you guys once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line will not clone an object, rather it will create a reference

```
 clone : props.type
```

To **clone** you can use various techniques (depending on your need) one simple one would be

```
 clone: Object.assign({}, props.type)
```

beware that this will only create a shallow copy of the object.
To create a deep copy you can use

```
 clone: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(props.type))
```

this is an easy technique but it is slow and will not copy dates correctly.
If you need fast and reliable deep clone you better search for something else that suits your needs (maybe a library like lodash).

Comment: hi! i have tried this solution too but it didn't work. maybe i'm handling this service wrong?

Comment: You need a deep clone, and pay attention not to mutate your state anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You're using state and props together in a way I wouldn't recommend.

Instead of trying to make a copy of the props and storing it as state, make a stateless function and pass down a function which handles the deletion.

Here is an example:

```js
class Child extends React.PureComponent {

  render () {
    return (<button onClick={this.props.handleBye}>{this.props.text}</button>)
  }

}

class Parent extends React.PureComponent {

  state = {
    text: "Hello"
  }
  
  handler = () => {
    this.setState({text: "bye"})
  }
  
  render() {
    return (<Child text={this.state.text} handleBye={this.handler} />)
  }ˆ
}




ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.body)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: hi! So, if i understand this right. You are saying that i should not try to clone the original object, instead i should callback to the parent and ask for it.

Comment: Yeah so basically, control the state in one location (the parent). Then send that state down to your component via props. This way you never have to worry about changing it, because it will be managed by the state in the parent. You can do any mutations you want in the handler that you pass down.

Comment: hey! Can you check out my edited question please? thank you

Comment: The answer is: yes. You must pass them all the way down to your component if you are using this method. However, solutions exist that solve this. Look into redux, react hooks, or the context api, which are all ways of reducing this long waterfall.

Comment: Thank you! I will look for it

Comment: Thank you! I will look for it

Answer (score 0):

**this.state.clone** is just a reference to the props.type object. So when you use `splice()` you change the contents of the array and therefore "mutate" `props.type`.

If you really want to clone the object do it like that:

```
this.state = {
  clone: {...props.type} // create a new object and spread the props.type object properties
}
```

You can read more about the spread operator [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)